# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(10), KEY vid (vid) )' at line 4

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have done an update on my site and got this error!

> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(10), KEY vid
>   (vid) )' at line 4

Coding is done in php 4... and sever is running on php 5

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$ine.C_MYSQL_VOTE_IPS." (
  vid smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ip int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0',
  time timestamp(10),
  KEY vid (vid)
)";
```

Comment: do you mean PRIMARY KEY(vid)?

Comment: Don't use MySQL reserved words (`time` is one of them).

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes for field names like  `` ` time `` ` = .

Comment: or give it a name that isn't a mysql reserved word: while "time" is one of the permitted exceptions, it might still cause problems